# I am getting data back but the array length is returned as 0

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to grab data from firebase and it console logs correctly but array says length is 0

[image: Code]

[image: Console.log]

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let items = [];
    const unsubscribe = store
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('redirects')
      .onSnapshot(snapShot => {
        snapShot.forEach(getPath => {
          const { path } = getPath.data();
          store.doc(path).onSnapshot(doc => {
            const data = doc.data();
            items.push({ ...data });
          });
        });
      });
    setDocs(items);
    setIsLoading(false);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  console.log(docs);
```

Comment: length is properly showed as 4 in the image. whats the issue here?

Comment: You can't really trust the console on chrome, it have some trouble displaying some variable it asynchronous context. Your problem is probably due to asynchronicity when you log the array it isn't yet updated

Comment: I updated it you can see it shows length 4 but then when you console log .length it shows 0 @yoga

Comment: it appears the dpcs variable is not completely refreshed with values in the chrome. if there is a discrepancy with console log and firebase database. i would ask you to create a new function to get the number from firebase once you are done with regular processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Your setState call should be inside the `onSnapShot(()=>{})` callback, because the it's asynchronous. The way you're doing, you're basically trying to call `setDocs()` with an empty `items` array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let items = [];
    const unsubscribe = store
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('redirects')
      .onSnapshot(snapShot => {
        snapShot.forEach(getPath => {
          const { path } = getPath.data();
          store.doc(path).onSnapshot(doc => {
            const data = doc.data();
            items.push({ ...data });
          });
        });
        setDocs(items);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    //setDocs(items);
    //setIsLoading(false);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it seems to be a async issue.
The console in chrome will show resolved object values, not necessarily what they were at run time. 
To show you what i mean, change your console log from `console.log(docs)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(docs))` and it will show you the string value of `docs` at run time which should be an empty array, which would make the length 0 make sense (because it is 0 until the async call is resolved).